# error( 23,13) Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Tags: java, android, repository

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWlLw.png)

Could anyone please help me in solving this problem. I have searched in google and other but unable to get any way to solve this problem.

I am getting this error in Android Studio error( 23,13) Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

Comment: install and sync

Comment: and update android studio to 3